# What does mode_t 0644 mean?

Tags: c, file-permissions

```
#define COPYMODE 0644
creat(argV[2],COPYMODE);
```

I have these two lines of code in a copy.c file.
I don't know what it means.
Please give some example about it

Comment: plus how to copy a file use a c program and maintain executable for the copy file

Comment: Remove semi-colon at end of `#define`

Answer (score 75):

There are 3x3 bit flags for a mode:

- (owning) User

  - read
  - write
  - execute
- Group

  - read
  - write
  - execute
- Other

  - read
  - write
  - execute

So each triple encodes nicely as an octal digit.

```
rwx oct    meaning
--- ---    -------
001 01   = execute
010 02   = write
011 03   = write & execute
100 04   = read
101 05   = read & execute
110 06   = read & write
111 07   = read & write & execute
```

So 0644 is:

```
* (owning) User: read & write
* Group: read
* Other: read
```

Note that in C, an initial `0` indicates octal notation, just like `0x` indicates hexadecimal notation. So every time you write plain zero in C, it's actually an *octal* zero (**fun fact**).

This might also be written:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

Whereas full permissions, 0777 can also be written:

```
-rwxrwxrwx
```

So the octal number passed to `creat` corresponds directly (via octal encoding of the bit-pattern) to the file permissions as displayed by `ls -l`.

Comment: I think it's better to explain them as bit flags

Comment: In this context `Owner` is uncommon. `User` is common. Also please see `man chmod` on this.

Comment: To not lose the meaning I'd propse to use the wording `(owning) User` instead of `Owner`..

Comment: By the way, why can we just say - 644, why 0644 is required?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI In C source, you must use an initial zero to specify an octal constant, otherwise it will be considered a decimal constant. With command-line tools like `chmod`, you may omit the `0` and `chmod` will interpret the number as an octal constant anyway.

Answer (score 19):

It means that:

- The file's owner can read and write (6)
- Users in the same group as the file's owner can read (first 4)
- All users can read (second 4)

See http://www.ss64.com/bash/chmod.html.

Comment: Very useful link @Rafe