# What does mode_t 0760 mean?

Tags: linux, pipe, named, mkfifo

I start today studying named pipe. I read that to create new named pipe i have to use this function: `mkfifo (const char* nom, **mode_t mode**);`

example:

```
if (mkfifo(("essai.fifo"), **0760**) == -1)
{

fprintf(stderr, "Can't create it");

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

My question is why in second argument we started with "**0** "(**0**760)
I know 7 give all permissions to the owner
6 means group can read and write
and the other doesn't have any permission

Comment: The leading zero represents octal. 0760 permissions would be user rwx (7 = 111b), group rw- (6 = 110b), other none (0 = 000b)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does mode\_t 0644 mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415904/what-does-mode-t-0644-mean)

Answer (score 2):

`760` is a decimal (base 10)

`0760` [leading 0] is an octal number (base 8)

`0x0760` [leading 0x] is a hex number (base 16)

The leading 0 isn't actually part of the number, just an indicator that it is octal, not decimal.

Answer (score 0):

As John3136 points out, the leading "0" signifies that the follow "number" (760) is octal and as you pointed out the permission bits for the new pipe would therefore be rwxrw---- for owner, group and everyone else.

Answer (score -2):

the first bit('0' of 0760 )represent the permission including  set-user-ID on execute bit, set-group-ID on execute bit and the sticky bit