# WordPress file permissions on CentOS7 requiring sudo

Tags: wordpress, permissions, centos

I'm running WordPress on my VPS with CentOS 7 LAMP stack.I've followed [this guide](http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2015/09/correct-permissions-for-wordpress/) to set permissions, i.e. I've run

`sudo chown apache:apache -R *` 
to ensure that my wordpress directory is owned by `apache:apache`.

I've also set WordPress directory and file permissions with these commands:

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

(I had to prefix the above commands with `sudo`)

Normally I manage the server by logging in through SSH using `myuser`, where `myuser` belongs to the `apache` group and the `wheel` group.

I have 3 problems:

1. Any file CRUD command in the WordPress directory still requires me to prefix the command with `sudo`, or else I get a permission error. Since `myuser` belongs to `apache` and `apache` owns the directory, I'm confused as to why I still need to prefix the commands with `sudo`.
2. Similar to problem 1, any `git` command such as a `git pull` requires me to prefix the command with `sudo` or else I get a permission error.
3. When I try to automatically update theme files from my WordPress dashboard web interface, I get permission errors. Interestingly, I'm able to install/update plugins via the WordPress dashboard without any permissions errors.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: I think this has very little to do with wordpress itself and SO is a much better place to ask it

Comment: @MarkKaplun according to [the help files](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), **server configuration for WordPress** is on topic. I suppose you could also argue that this is a generic server configuration and administration problem, which would _not_ be on topic.

Comment: I really hate people that pretend they are lawyers that are in court. Not every place in the world is a site of a tv drama

Comment: @MarkKaplun well I guess I would apologize if my comment offended you. tbh I wasn't exactly sure whether my question is appropriate in this forum, and since you were suggesting that it wasn't, I was just looking for some published guideline for reference.

Comment: If other people would like to offer some help on this question, please do. If not I'll be happy to just ask somewhere else. In fact, I had asked on serverfault, but I haven't gotten much help there.

Comment: it is a border line question, but since it might be a centOS specific thing and not even general linux question, the chances of finding people around here that have the knowledge are slim. just because sometthing falls into the definition of the site do not mean that this  is the best place to ask it

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's a centOS specific thing or not. The same principle could apply across different distros. I posted it here because I'm guessing that anyone who administers their own WordPress on their own VPS might have come across or be knowledgeable about this problem. I don't really think it hurts to ask here, but like I said I posted on serverfault too.

Comment: The amount of people that administer their own VPS and actually understand linux and not just copy&paste answer from SO or ask ubunto or the like is very very small

Comment: but in a way you are right, server fault is better place than SO

Comment: For a long time, I just copied and pasted snippets too. It's understandable - most people are not developers (or not sysadmins) and it's not part of their job. But now, I would like to actually learn it properly. I've found the stackexchange sites to be the best resource.

Comment: Could you maybe share what the current permissions of that WordPress directory (`$ ls -ld`) and its files/subdirectories are (`$ ls -al`)?

Comment: There's a chance this should go to SuperUser

Answer (score 7):

Look at:[What does mode_t 0644 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415904/what-does-mode-t-0644-mean#18415935)

```
644 means:
 * (owning) User: read & write
 * Group: read
 * Other: read
```

CRUD is a write command, so you're not allowed to do that. Either you change to `664` or keep using sudo. Basically any writing procedure on the file system would not be allowed without sudo since your user is not the owner (event though he is in the group).

Answer (score 3):

@fortuneRice, CentOS7 features selinux enabled by default, which is often the cause of many hard-to-understand file permission errors.

I would suggest the following:

1. Edit /etc/sysconfig/selinux
2. Change SELINUX=permissive (or whatever SELINUX is currently set to in the file) to **SELINUX=disabled**
3. Reboot your server (not just the apache web server, but the whole machine)

Disabling SELINUX completely is not a good idea, therefore if this procedure works, you should re-enable SELINUX and fix its configuration.

Configuring SELINUX can be a difficult task, so I suggest you read up on google how to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
chown -R -f user:apache /path of the directory
```

Comment: It is preferred to explain the command and how it'll solve the problem.

Comment: you should not give any permission to wordpress. Just place wordpress folder on server and change ownership to user (as written in command)

Comment: Ok, [edit] the answer and add the description in Answer. That way, future readers can see description in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced that issue and solved this problem by changing the PHP handler.

**it is important to use PHP Handler that will run as the file owner.**

After I installed HTTP2 and another few features on the way, I changed the PHP handler.

I am running WHM/CPanel on my VPS, and I fixed my issue following these steps:

1. Under `WHM` > `Software` > `EasyApache 4` > `Customize`

   Look for the: `mod_suphp` under the `Apache Modules` tab and make sure it is enabled, and if you just turned it on to install, follow step two.
2. Go to the `Review` tab and click the `Provision` button to save.
3. Under `Whm` > `Software` > `MultiPHP Manager` look for `PHP Handlers` tab.
4. Choose `suphp` as the handler for the current PHP version.

That's it. It was the PHP handler.

Edit: I notice that `suphp` had a conflict with one of my user uploads directories that I am adding dynamically to images a watermark. It seems the `suphp` handler had permission to upload but doesn't show the pictures.
I also tried the `lsapi` for the PHP Handler, and it seems to work correctly with the file's permissions and attaching via the .htaccess file watermarks for images.